# how do I convert multiple columns into a list in ascending order?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataset of this type:

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0:0 | 57:0 | 166:0 |
| 0:5 | 57:20 | 166:27 |
| 0:10 | 57:8: | 166:36 |
| 0:27 | 57:4 | 166:45 |

i want to convert this dataframe into an ascending list. I want to check the whole data into ascending order and then create a list using the ascending order numbers in the dataframe. and ascending order should be of numbers before ':'

desired output:

| list |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 57 |
| 166 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unstack` (or `stack`) to flatten to Series, then `extract` the number, convert to integer and keep the unique values in order:

For a python list you can try:

```
sorted(df.unstack()
         .str.extract('(\d+):', expand=False)
         .astype(int)
         .unique().tolist())
```

output: `[0, 57, 166]`

As Series:

```
out = (df.unstack()
         .str.extract('(\d+):', expand=False)
         .astype(int)
         .drop_duplicates()
         .sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

output:

```
0      0
1     57
2    166
dtype: int64
```